# Angular 12, Why doesn't the router guard work?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
  private get(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(urls.angular.signin_guard, authOptions);
  }

  pass: boolean = false;

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    this.get().subscribe(
      () => {
        this.pass = true;
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['/account/signin'], {relativeTo: this.route}).then();
        }
      }
    );
    return this.pass;
  }
```

1. expect: Send data to the backend, if the status code is 200, `this.pass=true`, if the status code is 401, jump to the login page
2. result: If the status code returned by the backend is 401, the page will jump to the home page and a blank page will be displayed

**Why is it so？**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a router to intercept requests, you should use an HttpInterceptor
Last little example

```
export class ApiInjectorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status !== 401) {
          console.log('dispose');
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probable `return this.pass;` is called before subscribe (and call do backend) is done.
In order to fix this you should return `Observable<boolean>` from your guard, not plain boolean, like this:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.get().pipe(
      map(response => // do something with response, like this (pseudocode)
            response.status === 200 ? true : false
            // so in result you will return Observable.of(true) or Observable.of(false)
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns `false` all the time, because you return guard result `(true/false)` before subscription of your get() function.

As you know browser's JS engine interpret the synchronous code at the first. Ex:

```
`return this.pass;`
```

then they will check for resolution of your async blocks like your:

```
`this.get().subscribe(){...}`
```

so the quick fix here is writing 2 different return expression inside subscribe call back functions.

Ex:

```
     canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        this.get().subscribe(
          () => {

            **return true;**
          },
          (error) => {

            if (error.status === 401) {
              this.router.navigate(['/account/signin'], {relativeTo: this.route}).then();

            **return false;**
            }
          }
        );
         }
```